# Loading a stored annotation's subtitle with NSUserDefaults when viewDidLoad

Tags: iphone, ios4, nsuserdefaults, mkannotation, mkannotationview

Basically, what I try to do is to save a subtitle(the street address) to an annotation. When the application terminates and starts again I want this stored subtitle to show up in the callout of the annotation. What am I doing wrong? I just can't get it to work...

storeLocation.m

```
- (void)setCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coor {
                  ............

                    NSUserDefaults *userDef = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
                    [userDef setValue:subtitle forKey:@"SavedAddress"];
                    [userDef synchronize];
                    NSLog(@"Stored subtitle");
                }
```

mainViewController.m

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
                NSString *savedAddress = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"SavedAddress"];
    if (savedAddress) {
    }                
}
```

Would really appreciate some help with this one... Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you state what is "not working"? Have you used NSLog to print out the values and try to find out what the stored values are returning?

Comment: No string at all returns when the application is relaunched.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try `srtingForKey:` instead of `objectForKey:`

```
NSString *savedAddress = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"SavedAddress"];
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with an if-statement in the

```
-(NSString *)subtitle.
```

So that:

```
-(NSString *)subtitle{

    NSUserDefaults *userDef = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    if ([userDef boolForKey:@"SavedAddress"]) {
        NSString *savedAddress = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"SavedAddress"];
        return savedAddress;
    }

    else {
        return subtitle;
    }
}
```